# Jquery code not working - seems really easy to fix - have fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulous

```
$('#tabs2').tabulous({
   effect: 'slideLeft'
});

$('#text1in').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#test1out').text(value);
}).keyup();

$('#text2in').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#test2out').text(value);
}).keyup();
```

Here is the new fiddle: [New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6urLv4j/)

It doesn't show the tabs working. I CAN get this working not on jsfiddle. But hopefully you will see what I am trying to do. I have both the tabs script working and the display field script working. I just can't seem to put them together. As soon as I add the form fields into the tabs-1 div container, it doesn't work. However, it does work outside of the tabs-1 div.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The fiddle gets an error because you didn't load the `tabulous` plugin. I'm not sure why you even need that, since there's no `#tabs` element in the HTML.

Comment: you are using a plugin called `tabulous` but haven't included that library script

Comment: check your browser console... there will be error message

Comment: I didn't include it because I didn't think it was causing any problems. Let me add the entire script if I can.

Comment: Like the other comments say, there is an error at the tabulous line. The script never makes it to the keyup functions, therefore the divs won't update

Comment: Have you tried moving lines 1-3 to the end?  Its possible that tabulous plugin is returning false which would prevent the remaining event handlers from executing.

Comment: @jtimperley Why would returning false prevent other code from running?

Comment: @Barmar  Returning false prevents the event from bubbling.  https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/  Also, if you reference the jquery code it will also stop executing handlers if false has been returned.  if ( event.result === false ) { event.preventDefault(); }

Comment: I'm working on a new fiddle with the tab plugin

Comment: @jtimperley But it's not in an event handler. And he's not returning its value.

Comment: @Barmar keyup and keydown aren't event handlers?  Event handlers are executed in the order they were added so if the first cancels, the rest do not get executed.

Comment: @jtimperley He's not calling `tabulous` from the keyup and keydown event handlers.

Comment: New fiddle here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/a6urLv4j/)

Comment: The new fiddle I just posted in the comment above doesn't show the tabs working. I can get this working not on jsfiddle. But hopefully you will see what I am trying to do. I have both the tabs script working and the display field script working. I just can't seem to put them together. As soon as I add the form fields into the tabs-1 div container, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple html, css, and javascript issues that need to be resolved.  I had to move the $().tabulous() initialization after the plugin was registered, fix your html for tabulous, fix a CSS style issue that caused the divs your pushing the text box values into to be hidden behind your text boxes.

Here is an example of what the HTML structure should look like.  http://www.noupe.com/development/tabulous-js-organize-random-content-in-tabs-with-jquery.html

HTML (Full):

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" title="">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" title="">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" title="">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4" title="">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5" title="">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-6" title="">Back</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="tabs_container">
<div id="tabs-1">
    <input id="text1in" type="text" value="some text" />
    <span id="test1out" class="tabulousclear"></span>
    <input id="text2in" type="text" value="some text" />
    <span id="test2out" class="tabulousclear"></span>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>2 - Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>3 - Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-4">
    <p>4 - Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-5">
    <p>4 - Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-6">
    <p>4 - Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
</div>

        </div><!--End tabs container-->

    </div><!--End tabs-->
```

CSS Added:

```
#tabs_container div
{
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Javascript (Full):

```
$('#text1in').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#test1out').text(value);
}).keyup();

$('#text2in').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#test2out').text(value);
}).keyup();

/*!
 * strength.js
 * Original author: @aaronlumsden
 * Further changes, comments: @aaronlumsden
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var pluginName = "tabulous",
        defaults = {
            effect: 'scale'
        };

       // $('<style>body { background-color: red; color: white; }</style>').appendTo('head');

    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.$elem = $(this.element);
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function() {

            var links = this.$elem.find('a');
            var firstchild = this.$elem.find('li:first-child').find('a');
            var lastchild = this.$elem.find('li:last-child').after('<span class="tabulousclear"></span>');

            if (this.options.effect == 'scale') {
             tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescale');
            } else if (this.options.effect == 'slideLeft') {
                 tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideleft');
            } else if (this.options.effect == 'scaleUp') {
                 tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hidescaleup');
            } else if (this.options.effect == 'flip') {
                 tab_content = this.$elem.find('div').not(':first').not(':nth-child(1)').addClass('hideflip');
            }

            var firstdiv = this.$elem.find('#tabs_container');
            var firstdivheight = firstdiv.find('div:first').height();

            var alldivs = this.$elem.find('div:first').find('div');

            alldivs.css({'position': 'absolute','top':'0px'});

            firstdiv.css('height',firstdivheight+'px');

            firstchild.addClass('tabulous_active');

            links.bind('click', {myOptions: this.options}, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $options = e.data.myOptions;
                var effect = $options.effect;

                var mythis = $(this);
                var thisform = mythis.parent().parent().parent();
                var thislink = mythis.attr('href');


                firstdiv.addClass('transition');

                links.removeClass('tabulous_active');
                mythis.addClass('tabulous_active');
                thisdivwidth = thisform.find('div'+thislink).height();

                if (effect == 'scale') {
                    alldivs.removeClass('showscale').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hidescale');
                    thisform.find('div'+thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showscale');
                } else if (effect == 'slideLeft') {
                    alldivs.removeClass('showleft').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hideleft');
                    thisform.find('div'+thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showleft');
                } else if (effect == 'scaleUp') {
                    alldivs.removeClass('showscaleup').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hidescaleup');
                    thisform.find('div'+thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showscaleup');
                } else if (effect == 'flip') {
                    alldivs.removeClass('showflip').addClass('make_transist').addClass('hideflip');
                    thisform.find('div'+thislink).addClass('make_transist').addClass('showflip');
                }

                firstdiv.css('height',thisdivwidth+'px');
            });
        },

        yourOtherFunction: function(el, options) {
            // some logic
        }
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            new Plugin( this, options );
        });
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );

$('#tabs').tabulous({
    effect: 'slideLeft'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't get this to work though. I used your code exactly as you said to. Here it is on a live test server. Please take out the spaces in the following domain: hop in it.com

Comment: It looks like the problem was with the opacity=0 on that div. This problem is solved!

Answer (score -2):

In your fiddle tabulous plugin are missing, If you remove the below lines from your code it work fine or install tabulous plugin properly.

```
$('#tabs2').tabulous({
   effect: 'slideLeft'
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This isn't an answer. He says in the question that removing these lines make it work, but he needs these lines.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned in last "install tabulous plugin properly"